# retained size is less than shallow size

Tags: java, heap-dump

```
select sum(heap.objects('char[]'), 'rsizeof(it)') / 1024 / 1024
```

returns 39

```
select sum(heap.objects('char[]'), 'sizeof(it)') / 1024 / 1024
```

returns 593

Does it mean that retain size (rsizeof) doesn't include the size of actual object? Or why is retain size less than shallow size?

Comment: I don't know rsizeof (which library/tool/part of the JDK are you using?) but it might be just the size of the retained set, i.e. retainedsize(it) = rsizeof(it) + sizeof(it).

Comment: I think I found it, you're referring to visualvm, right? According to the [doc](https://visualvm.java.net/oqlhelp.html#rsizeof) rsizeof "Returns size of the retained set of the given Java object in bytes". Thus it seems that it is the retained size minus the shallow size.